# Typescript 1.5 - 'Duplicate identifier' errors

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I created a very simplistic project with Typescript 1.5.0 beta and included **threejs/three** typings with tsd. When compiling, tsc outputs 128 errors regarding **Duplicate Identifier 'identifier'**. I'm not sure if 128 is just where tsc starts truncating errors, so there could be more...

I started the project by creating a blank folder, and creating app.ts and index.html. Then I installed **threejs/three** using the following command:

```
tsd install threejs/three -rso
```

In my app.ts I only added the following line, and compiled:

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
```

For now, compilation from the command line should suffice, and I'm using the following command:

```
tsc --module commonjs --target es5 ./app.ts
```

Here's link to the full list of errors I'm getting from tsc:

https://gist.github.com/josefvanniekerk/24496b480bf488db522d

Any idea why tsc complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `typings/webaudioapi/waa.d.ts`. TypeScript 1.5 includes Web Audio API declarations internally and you get duplicate identifiers.

To solve the problem, remove the `typings/webaudioapi/waa.d.ts` file and remove the reference to it from `typings/tsd.d.ts`

In previous versions of TypeScript compiler this file was not included and errors didn't show up.